# Is it possible to create diagonal pool pieces?

Tags: the-sims-3

You can place pool pieces in regular squares, use those rounded parts of two kinds, but I am wondering if it is possible to create diagonal pools as well? I want to build a pool in the corner of a garden where it is surrounded by three straight walls , but one corner has a diagonal angle in it. Can I fill up the two small grassy triangles up with pools as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly enough, they didn't add in diagonal pool pieces in The Sims 3. (Nor is there a way to 'trick' the game into creating a pool that looks like it has diagonal pieces.)